# Why in the world are French "Paul" and "Paule" distinguished by vowel openness?

Tags: language-change, french, gender, names, minimal-pairs

Wikipedia lists

> Paul [pɔl] ('Paul', masculine), vs. Paule [pol] ('Paule', feminine),

as a minimal pair of the two mid rounded back vowels of French.

What I wonder is, how did it happen that the two names came to be distinguished as such? What phonological development might it have been to do such a thing?

What further confuses me is that, if this was a case of irregular umlaut, shouldn't it be the other way around, since Latin *Paula* features [a], which is the most open of all the vowels?

Comment: I would need to check the charts to give a full answer, but note that the first syllable in _Paul_ has a coda and the first syllable in _Paule_ did not (back when the _e_ was pronounced).

Comment: Note that in the Southern half of France (Occitan substrate), both *Paul* and *Paule* are generally equally pronounced ['pɔlə].

Comment: I’m not sure if it’s a Québec thing, but Marie-Paule is generally pronounced [maripɔl] and not [maripol], even though Paule by itself is indeed pronounced [pɔl].